# excel macros for employee record

Tags: excel, vba

I am using excel 2010.
I have a sheet named 'LOG' in which there is a log of all the employee like this:

[image: Example Data]

Now I have another sheet named `sheet1`.
What I would like is a macro that should prompt for employee id and month, then display all the log of that employee for that particular month.

I have tried a lot of things but couldn't do it.

Comment: @idevelop...thanks for the tip. Just accepted the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will list the results in the column specified by the `RESULTS_COLUMN` constant value, just add the following code to your worksheet. You'll also need 3 named ranges - `EmployeeCode`, `StartDate` and `EndDate` - to input your criteria, though you could always prompt for these another way:

```
Sub DisplayRecords()

Const RESULTS_COLUMN As Long = 5

Dim strEmployeeCode As String
Dim dtStartDate As Date, dtEndDate As Date

Dim c As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrorTrap

    strEmployeeCode = [EmployeeCode]
    dtStartDate = [StartDate]
    dtEndDate = [EndDate]

    ' Clear the results column
    With Sheet1
        .Columns(RESULTS_COLUMN).ClearContents
        .Cells(1, RESULTS_COLUMN).Value = "Results"
        .Cells(1, RESULTS_COLUMN).Font.Bold = True
    End With

    For Each c In Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
        If c.Value = strEmployeeCode And c.Offset(, 1) >= dtStartDate And c.Offset(, 1) <= dtEndDate Then
            ' Find the next available cell in results column
            Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, RESULTS_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = c.Offset(, 1).Value
        End If
    Next c

    Exit Sub

ErrorTrap:
    MsgBox "An error has occurred, please check input criteria", vbExclamation, ThisWorkbook.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but how will this search month. I mean this will display all the log that is there for the employee. I want it to be show for that particular month for that employee.

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit. Have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: No problem bro. How to put all the content of msgbox in new sheet or sheet2

Comment: Code updated, just change the `Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, RESULTS_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value` to another sheet if you don't want to use Sheet1

Comment: Another option you may wish to consider, which will likely perform much faster on large sets of data is Advanced Filter:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP005200178.aspx